# rename and download amazon file ruby mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, mongoid, paperclip

When I click a link, the amazon file is downloading fine. I have thousands of pdf files in amazon. Now mongoid `id` as the name of that amazon files. When I download the the files its save with that id's. But I would like to rename the file before save that file to local. I have name field in my mongoid.

```
include Mongoid::Paperclip

has_mongoid_attached_file :profile_doc
```

when I link a like this controller action will call

```
def download 
  if @company.send(doc).exists?
    redirect_to @company.send(doc).expiring_url
  else
    respond_with_error(:not_found)
  end
end
```

How I rename the file when download the file. now file is downloading like this `50sfdkkmzd.pdf` I would like to save `name.pdf`.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280822/paperclip-rename-file-before-saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it should work fine

```
def download
  if @company.send(doc).exists?
    data = open(@company.send(doc).expiring_url)
    send_data data.read, :filename => "name.pdf", :type => data.content_type
  else
    respond_with_error(:not_found)
  end
end
```

Comment: And I would like to know why I should not use `send_file`.